# Used and unused space in an img file doesn't add up to total capacity

Tags: linux, disk-image

I had an image file of size 2.3gb that was almost full (only around 70MB unused space).

So in order to expand it, I used the command

`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1700MB >> ./image.img`

And then resized the partition using `parted`

However when I mount this new image, I am getting the same space unused (ie 70MB) and not 1.7GB.

GParted shows the extended space greyed out and I don't know why.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `truncate` to extend the image file.

e.g.

```
truncate -c -s 4G image.img
```

or

```
truncate -c -s +1700M image.img
```

see `man truncate` for more details.  The key detail from the man page is:

> If  a  FILE  is larger than the specified size, the extra data is
>   lost. If a FILE is shorter, it is extended and the extended part
>   (hole) reads as zero bytes.

You should then be able to edit the partition table to extend the partition to include the new space - you can use `parted`, `fdisk`, `gdisk`, `sfdisk`, `sgdisk` or other similar tools for this.

Once you've done that, you need to grow the filesystem so that it makes use of the newly available space.  According to the .png image you linked to, you are using ext4 for the filesystem, so you need to use `resize2fs` **after** editing the partition table.

You can use the `gparted` GUI to both extend the partition and grow the filesystem.

**NOTE:**  you should **always** make a backup copy of your image.img file before you do anything like this on it.  If anything goes wrong, you can always revert to the last known-good working image file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the append operator '>>' will work correctly with dd or not. I would recommend making an image2.img file the size you want, and then dd-ing your image.img file over the top of image2.img, then dd-ing it onto whichever partition you want it on. Instead of using image files you could do this directly to partitions, but be careful.

'dd if=/dev/zero of=image2.img count=4000MB bs=1M' then 'dd if=image.img of=image2.img bs=1M'

Comment: But doesn't the second dd command replace the first made image2.img(4GB) with an exact replica of the image.img? I am pretty sure it does....

Comment: Not with dd. dd will do bitwise copies. For example, if you dd an entire partition, /dev/sda5, with zeroes it will wipe the partition. Then you can dd in a partition image file that is smaller and it will just have extra space at the end. Install grub and it will detect the os just like any other. I have moved many partitions this way. Works the same as setting up luks encryption, first you create an encrypted partition, then you designate partitions inside of the encrypted partition. A file is just a pointer to somewhere in the fs. If you discover it doesn't work that way I'd like to know!